# How does one search for an exact phrase in Microsoft OneNote

Tags: windows, search, microsoft-onenote

Is it possible to search for an exact phrase in Microsoft OneNote in Windows? E.g., "The Fast and the Furious"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From
[OneNote Search Syntax](http://www.onenotegem.com/a/faq/onenote/2019/1126/1319.html) :

> **Use quotation marks to find an exact phrase**
>
> To search for an exact phrase, enclose the phrase in quotation marks.
> For example, if you type "Frank Lee" and you have notes that include
> the names Frank Miller, Oliver Lee, and Frank Lee, OneNote finds only
> those notes that include the exact phrase Frank Lee.

The following note might also be useful :

> **Use uppercase and lowercase letters interchangeably**
>
> With the exception of AND, OR, and NEAR, search is not case sensitive.
> For example, if you type Monday, OneNote finds notes that contain both
> monday and Monday.

Comment: I swear I've tried the quotes before without success, but now it works. Thanks for finking it, guys

Comment: Thanks, it was driving me crazy as searching "da" "de" or "di", all highlighted the words containing "de" ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  I have One Note (365) here.   I entered (for example) Windows Security Health (without quotes) and One Note found it right away. It finds results in all sheets in a notebook (tested). Search is not case sensitive (certainly in most cases). Quotes are not needed for simple searches but may be needed for more complex searches.

Open, or use, the One Note Search Bar (embedded in the top One Note bar) and type in your phrase. It will find it if it exists.

Notice it also offers numerous suggestions, so look above that for the item actually found.

Make sure Windows Search is running, and that USERS and Microsoft One Note are among the locations that is indexed, and possibly rebuild the index if you change something.

Comment: My experience is that will also find every instance of Windows, Security, and Health as well as all the lower case instances. Moreover, it's inclined to also find variations of the words. E.g., If I'm searching for "Fast and Furious" it will spit out something like "a faster way of doing that..."

Comment: Windows Search is not normally case sensitive. I entered my test in lower case. I also do not (did not) enclose my phrase in quotes.  I have done numerous tests when and since I posted and they all worked.

Comment: @Ed S -- I clarified my answer to note that quotes are normally not needed for simple searches by might be required for more complex searches and that searches are normally not case sensitive.  You may have to experiment a bit.  Also ignore Suggestions and look only at matches.